# How to return a generic struct in Rust

Tags: rust, return-type

Beginner in Rust, I'm wondering how to return generic data in a function.

```
pub fn tryparse() -> (CLIAction, ArgSingle) {
    let args = CLI::from_args();
    match args.cmd {
        SubCommand::Add(opt) => {
            (CLIAction::QuantityAdd,opt)
        }
        SubCommand::Del(opt) => {
            (CLIAction::QuantityDel,opt)
        }
    }
}
```

In this example both `Add` and `Del` get a `ArgSingle` struct type. However I'd like to implement a `Search` that would use a `ArgSearch` struct type, and return it... How to tell rust that `tryparse()` can return either `ArgSingle` or `ArgSearch` type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple return types from a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296223/multiple-return-types-from-a-method)

Comment: That's a complicated question, there are many ways to solve this. For example, implement a trait that combines both and then return a `Box<CombinedArg>` instead of an `ArgSingle`. Another possibility is to return an enum that can carry both. I think more context is required for a proper answer.

Comment: Also, mandatory meta-comment: If you need a CLI, i strongly recommend [clap](https://docs.rs/clap) :)

Comment: @Finomnis I'm actually using StructOps which is based on clap afaik. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Quote from structops: `As clap v3 is now out, and the structopt features are integrated into (almost as-is), structopt is now in maintenance mode: no new feature will be added.` Structops got integrated into clap v3. Use clap directly instead. Although I'm aware this doesn't have anything to do with your actual question.

Comment: @Finomnis DANG! You got me here. I'm very new to Rust, so this crate game is still fresh and I'm scared to do some mistakes here. I knew StructOps was based on clap... but not that clap had integrated StructOps features. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: This kind of thing is rare, so don't worry, you won't encounter it often. Clap just thought that StructOpts idea of making it `derive` based is so cool they wanted to do that as well. So they paired up with the structops devs, made a lot of alpha versions (for about half a year) until they had an API they were happy with and then released it as clap v3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to return either `ArgSingle` or `ArgSearch` from `tryparse()` function. There are a few approaches to that, a common one is to use enumerations as the return.

First, define an enum that represents all the possible types that can be returned from the function:

```rust
enum CLIResult {
    Single(ArgSingle),
    Search(ArgSearch),
}
```

Then, modify the function to return this enum inside of the tuple:

```rust
pub fn tryparse() -> (CLIAction, CLIResult) {
    let args = CLI::from_args();
    match args.cmd {
        SubCommand::Add(opt) => {
            (CLIAction::QuantityAdd, CLIResult::Single(opt))
        }
        SubCommand::Del(opt) => {
            (CLIAction::QuantityDel, CLIResult::Single(opt))
        }
        SubCommand::Search(opt) => {
            (CLIAction::Search, CLIResult::Search(opt))
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the function can return either `ArgSingle` as `CLIResult::Single` or `ArgSearch` as `CLIResult::Search`.

To use the return value of `tryparse()`, you would need to pattern match on the `CLIResult` enum to extract the appropriate type of result. For example:

```rust
let (action, result) = tryparse();
match result {
    CLIResult::Single(single_arg) => {
        // Handle single argument case
    }
    CLIResult::Search(search_arg) => {
        // Handle search argument case
    }
}
```